mod_rewrite doesn't work hiding the file extension
In the root directory there is a .htaccess file, in the directory next to it there are html files to which the rule should apply, but for some reason it does not work.
.htaccess code
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^redirect/files/moved.zip$ /redirect/media/moved.zip [L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html?$ /$1 [R=301,L]


site-avalible config
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/lab2
    ServerName  lab2

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile ssl/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl/cert.key

    <Directory /var/www/lab2>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


I changed the access rights to rewrite in the Apache configuration, which I also did in the configuration of the "lab2" site, but it did not work.
